# html 5 audio pause and play issues

Tags: html, audio

http://jsfiddle.net/BC2VC/

I built an extremely simple audio player. Its just a `.png` in the `background-image:` of a `<button>` that uses `.toggleClass()` to change the background position of the `.png` showing a pause button.

I used javascript code that I found on a w3 reference which is a function that links the audio players play and pause events to the `<button>`.

I have three problems...

One, I cant figure out how to get one audio track to stop when the next when is clicked. I only want one track at a time to be able to play.

Two, if you click the play button for track one it switches to a pause button as it should, but then clicking on track two , both track one and two will show pause buttons. I need track one to switch back to a play button when any other play button is clicked, only one track at a time should show the pause symbol.

The third problem is: The code in the jsfiddle link above works to play the audio everywhere Ive tested except in jsfiddle.

here is a link to a page using the same exact code on my godaddy server...

http://liveoilfree.com/wtrclrwtrclr/index3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'd recommend using one `<audio>` object and change it's source when user presses play on another song.
2. Use a javascript `for`-loop to reset all the play buttons except the active one.

Link that might help:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/